# Tree-shaped diagrams (e.g. organigrams) with smartdiagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

Is it possible to build tree-shaped diagrams (e.g. organigrams) using the smartdiagram package?

What would be the best kind of smartdiagram (circular, flow, constellation,...) to use to this end?

In my case it would be enough to have a constellation diagram (say with three sons), e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
Build a program,Set up,Run,Analyze
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

but with the center node at the top.

I was wondering whether (for example) it is easy to hide some of the satellites and use a constellation diagram of the appropriate size with the top nodes hidden.

Comment: Why would you use something that has no tree-features to make a tree?

Comment: Well, part of my question was whether it has tree-features that I was not aware of, and in part because I like the non-shaped related features of the package.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not super familiar with the package, but I would suppose the manual describes what is on offer, and it looks like the closest you can get is a flow diagram with additions, but it's not really a tree. What does "non-shaped related features" mean?

Comment: I mean "features of the package not related to the shape of the diagram".

Comment: What's an 'organigram' anyway?

Comment: i'm not very familiar with this package, but for tree.shaped diagrams is (to me) naturally use packages which support drawing trees, like `tikz` or even beer `forest. all fancy stuff of `smartdiagram can be done also in both of aforementioned packages. for concrete help provide image what you like to have and what you do so far. generally speaking, your question is matter of opinion and probably will be closed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizational_chart

Comment: IMHO not every question needs a MWE. Sorry for being so sacrilegious, and thank you anyway.

Comment: I do agree with you that not every question needs an MWE, but when we're at this stage anyway: You say a constellation diagram with one modification would be enough, so why not just add an example of such a diagram to your question (without the modification, of course)? That said, such a modification would entail essentially redefining what `smartdiagram` does, so it would probably be easier to use some other tool. (In a `constellation`, the first element in the list is the center node, and the others are distributed around it with at evenly spaced angles.)

Comment: Thank you Torbjørn, it is nice to receive a reasonable answer.

Comment: Given that any answer is probably going to involve ditching `smartdiagram`, could you say what about the output from the code in your question you want to keep?

Comment: I wonder if you'd be better looking at mind maps. They seem more similar to the picture you've got, but are tree-like (or can be configured to be tree-like). I tried taking your code an making it into a tree and realised I had no idea at all what you wanted to do with it. Right now, I think the question is just too unclear.

Comment: I just wanted a fancy rooted tree (intended as an organigram). I liked the look of smartdiagram and I wondered whether it was easy to convert one of its diagrams into a rooted tree (and skip some makeup). After your comments I think that maybe it is better to draw it directly with plain tikz. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @suitangi I think if you basically want one big circle at the top with three smaller circles overlapping the bottom arc of that circle, say, in the style of `smartdiagram`, then it would, indeed, be easiest to just draw it in Ti*k*Z. If you want something more tree-like than bubble-like, then I'd use Forest or `tikz-qtree` or the `trees` library. If you want fancy connections between circular nodes (like shaded bridges from one to the other), then look at the mind maps support. I think the problem here is that it is really unclear what you want the result to be, so it is very hard to help.

Comment: If you can clarify your question a bit, it can be re-opened. I'm reluctant to vote to reopen right now because I don't understand the question, so I can't see how anybody can answer it.

Comment: OK, when I find a clearer way to ask the question I'll post it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to mimmic `smartdiagram` styles with more tree-oriented tools like `forest`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{forest}
for tree={circle, minimum size=2cm, 
      edge={red, line width=1mm, shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt, ->}}
[Build a program, fill=red!30
[Set up,fill=blue!30]
[Run, fill=green!30]
[Analyze,fill=violet!30]]
\end{forest}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]